# Filter Log File

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, nunit

I have a Log file which is Log output of Nunit Runner

I want to parse through the file to extract the data;

Here is the sample Log File :
[image: Log File Contents]

I want to extract the Test Count, Passed and Failed Tests

How to use Regex to get the data.

I am Using Pattern and Scanner Classes to Scan the data.

Here is the sample function i am using to read the file 
[image: Function to Read File]

UPDATE:

I have Used the following Code to extract Test Results, I would like have suggestions on this code:

```
  public int FilterLogFile(File LogFile) {
    int TestCount = 0;
    try {


        String Line = "";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(LogFile));
        while ((Line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(Line);
            String line = scanner.findInLine(".*(Test Count:)\\s+\\d+\\D+\\s+.*(Passed:)\\s+\\d+\\D+\\s+.*(Failed:)\\s+\\d+");
            if (line != null) {
                System.out.println("Detected Line: " + line);
                TestCount = ExtractData(Line);
                break;
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return TestCount;
}

 private int ExtractData(String strLine) {
    int Count = 0;
    try {

        String[] Data = strLine.split(",");
        for (String str : Data) {
            if (str.contains("Test Count:")) {
                int value = Integer.parseInt(str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
                Count = value;
                System.out.println(value);
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Count;
}
```

Sample Log I am working on is :

[image: Log File Contents]

Comment: Instead of posting images of text you might want to post the text instead (there are tags for code etc.). Also, what did you try so far? How would _you_ try to extract the data? And what do you already know of regular expressions? (If you don't know much I'd suggest you first grab some tutorial on those and try something yourself).

Comment: I'd recommend instead parsing this information from the xml results file NUnit produces. The log output may change in future NUnit versions.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helpful for you,

use this,

```
a = "[test run server,overall result: Failed, Test count:09, Passed: 14, Failed: 1, skipped: 16, start: 1, end: 10, asd: asd,akdsu]"

/Test.+.(?:Failed:.\d+)/
```

Regex: `/Test.+.(?:Failed:.\d+)/`